# Remove words contained in a file from another text file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I know similar questions have been posted but I haven't been able to find the answer for my query. So I have a text file and another file containing a list of stop words (http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt). I need to remove the words present in the common-english-words.txt from my text file.

Comment: Hint: consider `grep` with its `-v` and `-f` options.

Comment: @bishop That'd remove whole lines...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

```
sed 's/,/ /g' filename >> out.txt (to change the commas into white space)

tr ' ' '\n' <out.txt >>out1.txt (to put all the stop words onto new lines)

tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < JJ.txt | fgrep -i -v -w -f out1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort - nr | head -20 (for counting the most frequent 20 words excluding the stop words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining a few tools could give you a hint.

```
sed 's/('"$(tr ',' '|' < common-english-words.txt)"')//g' myfile.txt > out.txt
```

I see the `common-english-words.txt` file is a list of words separated by commas, so if you replace the commas with bars, you get a regex matching any one of them. Then you can use `sed` to remove them.

The actual command executed looks like:

```
sed 's/(a|able|about|...)//g' myfile.txt > out.txt
```

which just removes the word from the list and sends the output to `out.txt`.